# How to export a visualized ROI in google earth engine in tif file format

Tags: javascript, google-earth

i want to export a visualized ROI in google earth engine in tif file format

```
Map.addLayer(ROI,{},"Region");
Map.centerObject(ROI,16);

var waterOccurrence = water.select('occurrence');
Map.addLayer(waterOccurrence, {palette: ['blue']},'Global Water Body');

var visWater = {min:0, max: 100, palette: ['red','yellow','green']};
Map.addLayer(waterOccurrence.updateMask(waterOccurrence), visWater,
"Water Occurrence Change (1984-2015)");
```

this what i have visualized

i want to export this in tif fromat. but when i try to do it i am getting a tif file which size is in kbs.